# Vue WSL Ubuntu -"HelloWorld.vue" dependency not found" when deleting HelloWorld.vue component in new app

Tags: vue.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Brand new installation, installed Vue via vue cli. Run `vue create app` and set up with basic configuration.
Delete HelloWorld.vue component and the accompanying import code from Home.vue.
Run `npm run serve` and am immediately met with

> This dependency was not found:
>
> @/components/HelloWorld.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/components/HelloWorld.vue

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Vue, updating all dependencies,
everything I can think of. Did a global search for "helloworld" and there is no trace of it.

Everything works fine on my Mac.
Any help would be great.

Comment: delete your `node_module` directory and re-install all dependecies

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Home.vue file located in the views folder and completely remove the HelloWorld.vue component.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue. New Vue Project from VueCLI... Using Visual Studio code. Latest of Yarn (not NPM), latest VS Code. Node. Vue 3 preview.

Had me baffled for a few minutes. Even after I delete the node_modules it still didn't work.

*I think this may be a different reason than your issue, but maybe this might save someone else a few minutes...*

So.. What fixed it for me? Its going to sound stupid... but here it goes anyway!:

I was using Visual Studio Code and I didn't have **AutoSave** on, so after **I explicitly saved my renamed HelloWorld.vue file and saved all the dependences like App.vue files etc.  I yarn installed and run again, and it worked..**
oh boy... duh! (Face-Palm moment)